# Show that, if $u,v,w$ are orthogonal two-by-two, then $S = \{ u , v , w\}$ forms a basis which is linearly independent

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am given the following question:

> Show that, if $u,v,w$ are orthogonal two-by-two, then $S = \{ u , v , w\}$ forms a basis which is linearly independent.

My idea to tackle this problem is to say that

$$
u . v = 0 \Rightarrow (u_1, u_2, u_3) \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3) = 0 \Rightarrow u_1 v_1 + u_2 v_2 + u_3 v_3 = 0\\
v . w = 0 \Rightarrow (v_1, v_2, v_3) \cdot (w_1, \cdots \\
\cdots
$$

and that

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ 
w_1 & w_2 & w_3
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0
$$

but I'm pretty sure that's not the way to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$au+bv+cw=0$$
Then dot product by $u$ gives
$$a u\cdot u + 0 + 0 = 0$$
$$a=0$$
Dot product by $v$ gives
$$0+b v \cdot v + 0=0$$
$$b=0$$
Dot product by $w$ gives
$$0+0+c w\cdot w=0$$
$$c=0$$
Hence they are linearly independent.

Comment: You mean that the only solution possible is the trivial one?

Comment: Yes. The definition of linear independence of a set of vectors is that only the trivial linear combination gives $0$.

Comment: Thank you, have a great day. Best Regards!